# mailx does not deliver mails anymore

Tags: solaris, sendmail, email

On my Solaris machine, mailx suddenly stopped delivering mail messages.

When running the following sample command:

```
echo "test" | mailx -vvv -s "test" [reciever]
```

I get the following output:

```
[receiver]... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 [local server] ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.5+Sun/8.14.5; Fri, 18 Apr 2014 16:20:59 +0200 (CEST)
>>> EHLO [local server]
250-[local server] Hello nas1 [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<[sender]> SIZE=58
250 2.1.0 <[sender]>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<[receiver]>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <[receiver]>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <[receiver]>... Connecting to aspmx.l.google.com. via esmtp...
050 220 mx.google.com ESMTP o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp
050 >>> EHLO [local server]
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [93.99.164.77]
050 250-SIZE 35882577
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-STARTTLS
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250 CHUNKING
050 >>> STARTTLS
050 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
050 >>> EHLO [local server]
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [93.99.164.77]
050 250-SIZE 35882577
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250 CHUNKING
050 >>> MAIL From:<[sender]> SIZE=354
050 250 2.1.0 OK o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp
050 >>> RCPT To:<[receiver]>
050 250 2.1.5 OK o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp
050 >>> DATA
050 354  Go ahead o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp
050 >>> .
050 250 2.0.0 OK 1397831998 o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp
050 <[receiver]>... Sent (OK 1397831998 o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp)
250 2.0.0 s3IEKxlS006286 Message accepted for delivery
[receiver]... Sent (s3IEKxlS006286 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 [local server] closing connection
```

And the following lines appear in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 18 16:20:59 nas1 sendmail[6285]: [ID 801593 mail.info] s3IEKxjm006285: from=[sender], size=58, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201404181420.s3IEKxjm006285@[local server]>, relay=[sender]@localhost
Apr 18 16:21:00 nas1 sendmail[6286]: [ID 801593 mail.info] s3IEKxlS006286: from=<[sender]>, size=354, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201404181420.s3IEKxjm006285@[local server]>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=nas1 [127.0.0.1]
Apr 18 16:21:00 nas1 sendmail[6286]: [ID 702911 mail.info] STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Apr 18 16:21:00 nas1 sendmail[6286]: [ID 801593 mail.info] s3IEKxlS006286: to=<[receiver]>, ctladdr=<[sender]> (60005/10), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30354, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.70.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1397831998 o46si40562775eem.39 - gsmtp)
Apr 18 16:21:00 nas1 sendmail[6285]: [ID 801593 mail.info] s3IEKxjm006285: to=[receiver], ctladdr=[sender] (60005/10), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30058, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s3IEKxlS006286 Message accepted for delivery)
```

It seems that the SMTP server at Google accepted the message correctly. How can I find out the source of the error?

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, the mail is not in the spam folder either.

Comment: Could you post log entries generated by "non delivered" messages?

Comment: @DušanRychnovský Did you ever solve this problem? I have started experiencing the same thing only recently.